# Scheme Understanding

Tags: scheme

I am supposed to write a scheme function (digit-count n) that accepts a positive integer n and evaluates to the number of digits of n that are 6, 4, or 9.

I am having trouble understanding what exactly I am supposed to do, I am confused about the "digits of n that are 6, 4 or 9", what does this mean?

Comment: This seems like a great question for your teacher.  However I think you are to remove all numbers that are not 6, 4, or 9.  So the result of input 61144119 would be 4, 6449.  You should start by converting your input to a string.

Comment: @linuxuser27 Nothing about the name 'digit-count' implies that digits are to be removed. This homework question can be done using only math.

Comment: @erjiang - I was walking the OP through the concept of what I thought the teacher was asking.  The digits in the number that are 6, 4, 9.  Please tell me how you would do this without converting 61144119 to a string or list in scheme. Considering every solution is using that approach.

Comment: @linuxuser27 I don't want to give away a homework question, but *psst* there's a function called "quotient" in Scheme.

Comment: Yes I know.  But see, that is what is interesting. You interpreted the question as 'How many multiples of 6 4 and 9' are in a specific number.  Everyone else interpreted it as 'Given a number, how many 6 4 and 9 digits are in its decimal representation.'  As there are 2 '6's and 1 '4' in the number 646.

Comment: @linuxuser27 Last comment from me, but you can use (remainder x 10) to get the ones digit and then pass (quotient x 10) to the next recursive step.  This way, you can count how many of certain digits are present in the base-10 representation of the number.  We have given very similar homework questions in the past to our students.

Answer (score 4):

This is just an interpretation question, but I would say that you would take the decimal representation of a number, and count the total number of digits that are 6, 4, or 9. For example:

- 100 --> 0
- 4 --> 1
- 469 --> 3
- 444 --> 3

Get it now?

Answer (score 0):

One interpretation - example:

Given `678799391`, the number of digits would be `0` for `4`, `1` for `6` and `3` for `9`. The sum of the occurences would be `0 + 1 + 3 = 4`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the whole number to a list and check each one individually.

```
(define (number->list x) 
  (string->list (number->string x))

(define (6-4-or-9 x) (cond ((= x 6) true)) ((= x 4) true)) ((= x 9) true))))

(define (count-6-4-9 x) (cond ((6-4-or-9 (car (number->list x)))).......
```

I'm sure you can see where that's going. It's pretty crude, and I'm not sure it's really idiomatic, but it should work.

The idea is is that you convert the number to a list, check to first digit, if it's six, four or nine, recursively call the procedure on the cdr of the number list converted back to a string + 1...

Comment: Better to use `or` instead of `cond`.  Even better -- use `member`.  Also -- `string->list` returns a list of characters, so you should be used `#\6` etc, not `6`.

Comment: Thanks Eli! I'm still kind of new to scheme, I bet you can tell!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using lists, you can work with modulo `%` of 10 and dividing whole numbers `/` with 10.

Below is the recursive solution :

```
(define (digits n)
(if(not (< n 1)) (+ 1 (digits (/ n 10))) 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we must understand what the question is asking: It is asking you to write a procedure that counts the number of times the numbers 4, 6, or 9 show up in another inputted number. For instance, inputting `10345` should return `1`. Let's see why:

The digits of `10345` are `1`, `0`, `3`, `4`, and `5`. We have to ask, "How many times do `4`, `6`, or `9` show up?" Well, there are no `6`'s or `9`'s in `10345`. However, there is one `4`. Therefore, the procedure should return `1`.

Another example: `(digit-count 14289)`

Let's break it up like we did before. The digits of `14289` are `1`, `4`, `2`, `8`, and `9`. There are no `6`'s. There are, however, `1`'s and `9`'s. How many? There is one `1` and one `9`. Since there are two (total) of the desired digits present (desired digits are `4`, `6`, and `9`), `(digit-count 14289)` should return `2`.

Some more examples:

`(digit-count 144)` --> `2` (there are two `4`'s)

`(digit-count 1)` --> `0` (there are no `4`'s, `6`'s, or `9`'s)

`(digit-count 1262)` --> `1` (there is one `6`)

Now, let's start defining. We can take advantage of the `appearances` function, which takes two inputs and returns how many times the first input *appears* in the second. 
For example: `(appearances 'a 'amsterdam)` returns `2` because there are two `a`'s in `amsterdam`.

Using `appearances`, here is our definition (finally!):

```
(define (count469 num)
  (+ (appearances 4 num)
     (appearances 6 num)
     (appearances 9 num)))
```

This function returns the sum of the `appearances` of 4, the `appearances` of 6, and the `appearances` of 9. Please feel free to reply with any feedback or questions!